# Set property of object through prototype method

Tags: javascript, prototype, underscore.js

I'm creating a small lib to interact with MongoLab HTTP API, but I'm having some issues. I'm using CommonJS modules.

I have a Model object, made to behave as prototype for the other models:

```html
module.exports = {
    //[...]

    //this will be overriden by the other models
    fields: ['id'],

    setFields: function(values) {
        _.each(this.fields, function(field) {
            this[field] = values[field]
        })
    }
}
```

And I have, for example, an User model:

```html
var Model = require('models/Model')

function User (properties) {

    this.fields = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'surname',
        'email',
        'password'
    ]

    this.setFields(properties)

    //[...]
}
```

There, the `setFields()` call works correctly, iterating through each of the five fields given in the User model; although, it won't set the User properties. If I add a `console.log(this.name)` before the end of the `setFields()` definition, it will give me `undefined`. The only way I got to workaround the issue was passing the `this` object as argument for the `setFields` method, and using the argument instead of `this`.

It looks like a scope problem for me, but I'm still quite new with JavaScript OO, so... What's wrong with my logic?

Comment: Oh, and I'm [Underscore.js's each method](http://underscorejs.org/#each).

Comment: You will need to show more code. For example, as per the code shown there is NO connection between `User` and `Model`. Also, how is the instance of `User` created? Share more code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a `context` parameter to `_.each` to set the `this` context you're expecting in your callback function:

```
setFields: function(values) {
    _.each(this.fields, function(field) {
        this[field] = values[field];
    }, this);  // context parameter that establishes this in your callback
}
```

Comment: How did I not see that? :( ... Nice catch.

Comment: duh. I tried to use the given context argument, but.... inside the callback function, not as a third argument for _.each() haha
ty!